# Maintenance page - display the error

Tags: magento2, html, maintenance

[Magento 2]

I have a maintenance page which appears on some order view (eg: xxx/sales/order/view/order_id/123/xxx) on my BO of Magento (but not on all pages).

I try to understand what is the issue but I don't find any log: I take a look in system.log, exception.log and in all file.log I have without success.

My maintenance page is configured in BO > Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > fastly Configuration > Custom Synthetic Pages > Error/Maintenance Page HTML. Currently, it's only display "Maintenance Page.".

What can I put in this html page to display the issue or at least, where the logs are created?

Comment: you are using custom module for maintenance page right? you can check with default magento maintenance

Comment: Yes, I use custom Fastly module. I can't display error  in the html page? It's not possible with my custom module?